# Python - Sort Dictionary Key Alphabetically while sorting Value list elements by length

Tags: python, list, function, sorting, dictionary

I have a Dictionary here:

```
test_dict = {'gfg': ['One', 'six', 'three'], 
             'is': ['seven', 'eight', 'nine'], 
             'best': ['ten', 'six']}
```

I tried:

```
for i in range(len(test_dict)):
                values = list(test_dict.values())
                keys = list(test_dict)
                value_sorted_list = values[i]
                value_sorted_list = keys[i]
                keys_sorted_list = random.shuffle(value_sorted_list)
                test_dict.update({f"{keys_sorted_list}":value_sorted_list})
```

I want to sort the keys alphabetically while the value list by length
Something like this:

```
test_dict = {'best': ['six', 'ten'], 
             'gfg': ['One', 'six', 'three'], 
             'is': ['nine', 'eight', 'seven]}
```

I also want another function similar to the one i mentioned above but if the elements are similar length, to sort them randomly.

As well as another function to sort value list randomly.

Comment: "I want to sort the keys alphabetically"... "I tried... `random.shuffle(value_sorted_list)`"... `random.shuffle`, seriously? And no code to sort anywhere. Please do not insult our intelligence by posting random code as your "attempt" just so that you think you can make us think you've put an effort into solving this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting keys alphabetically and values by length.

```
new_dict = {}
for key in sorted(test_dict.keys()):
    sorted_values = sorted(test_dict[key], key=len)
    new_dict[key] = sorted_values
print(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) preserves insertion order since 3.7.

> Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

Therefore, you can simply construct a new dictionary according to the sorted key and ensure the corresponding value is sorted. From the output your posted, the value is sorted by length first then alphabetically.

```py
result = {key: sorted(value, key=lambda x: (len(x), x)) for key, value in sorted(test_dict.items())} # Thanks to Masklinn
print(result)
# {'best': ['six', 'ten'], 'gfg': ['One', 'six', 'three'], 'is': ['nine', 'eight', 'seven']}
```

Reference:

[`dict-comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dict) - a way to construct a dictionary

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#sorted) - The key function here achieves sorting by length first then alphabetically. You can change it according to your sorting rules.

Comment: This is way over-complicated though, you can sort the items directly, and there's no requirement to sort the values lexicographically ("if the elements are similar length, to sort them randomly."). So `{k: sorted(v, key=len) for k, v in sorted(test_dict.items())}` ought do. One trick is that since dict keys are unique by definition, `sorted` won't need to consider the values so it wouldn't matter if they were not ordered (though lists of strings are).

Comment: Thanks for the supplement. I just infer that from the expected output in OP. For the key `'best'`, its value is `['six', 'ten']` rather than `['ten', 'six']`.

Comment: @Masklinn, I think `sorted(test_dict)` does the same thing as `sorted(test_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[0])`, without introducing additional cost of comparing values. But with the latter we can unpack key and value simultaneously.

Comment: there is no "additional cost of comparing values", and iterating on the keys only means the additional cost of indexing after iterating, which is entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a dictionary comprehension as follows:

```
test_dict = {'gfg': ['One', 'six', 'three'], 
             'is': ['seven', 'eight', 'nine'], 
             'best': ['ten', 'six']}

new_dict = {k:sorted(v, key=len) for k, v in sorted(test_dict.items())}

print(new_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'best': ['ten', 'six'], 'gfg': ['One', 'six', 'three'], 'is': ['nine', 'seven', 'eight']}
```